# how to alias external commands in emacs 27

Tags: emacs

I am trying to get Emacs 27 working for javascript + flow.
There are many steps/packages/configs to get this to work.

One particular step I am currently stuck on.

I cannot install npm packages globally (because our monorepo uses different versions of node_module packages for different apps within the repo).
So we cannot install flow, typescript and other things with npm -g
Instead, we need to point emacs to ./node_modules/.bin/flow   (as an example).

Here is a concrete error message I am getting when starting emacs

```
Command "javascript-typescript-stdio" is not present on the path.                                                                      
Command "typescript-language-server --stdio" is not present on the path.                                                               
Command "flow lsp" is not present on the path.
```

So, I would like, if possible to define in my .emacs
javacript-typescript-stdio
typescript-language-server
flow

such that they  will point to  /node_modules/.bin/
where   is directory from which I start emacs

When searched for this topic, most queries came back with something about aliasing internal emacs functions, but that's not what I am looking for.

My .emacs section relevant to this:

```
;; lsp-javascript specific start
;; https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/489
(use-package js2-mode
  :mode "\\.js\\'"
  :init
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'js2-imenu-extras-mode)
  (setf js2-mode-indent-inhibit-undo t)
  :config
  (with-eval-after-load "lsp-javascript-typescript"
    (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'lsp)))


;; for flow start
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'flow-minor-enable-automatically)
;; for flow end 


;; JSON
(use-package json-mode
  :defer t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exec-path` holds locations to search for executables, so adding an entry there should work,

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "./node_modules/.bin")
```

In this case, the path is relative to `default-directory`, which see.